# How to push Swift code to client through server in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, http, socket.io

I want my app to make urgent security updates without going through Apple's review process. I am not trying to do this for all my updates, or circumvent Apple's reasonable review requirements. All it would have to do is push a .swift file to the client, which would be accessed somewhere in the app.

I definitely know there is a way to do it in JavaScript, as I already made a mechanism of the same type in a React Native. I used [this approach](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/), but I don't think there is an equivalent for iOS from what I've heard.

There definitely is a solution, as I've heard many devs doing this (for less, um... *valid* reasons) but I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this, for both technical and policy reasons. Apple expressly forbids you from delivering new code to your apps's outside of the app store process.

The other part of it is that your apps run compiled object code, not source code. Aside from the iPad Swift playgrounds app, there is no Swift compiler on the user's devices.

Javascript is a horse of a different color. That's an interpreted language, and is designed to be delivered and run dynamically.

Comment: This would be a heck of a stunt if you could do it, though...produce a new binary from an existing one plus some source as a patch. Probably somebody's PhD thesis. Then relaunch the process in place.

Comment: I read somewhere that it is possible via method Swizzling, but that got obsolete I think.

Comment: Method swizzling is a technique of using the Objective-C runtime to replace the implementation of existing methods (in either your classes or system classes) with custom code. It has nothing to do with deploying new source code to an installed app in the field.

Comment: OK... too bad though, security is one the main aspects of my app and Apple's process takes way too long to effectively make any security updates. But I'll make manual updates for now.

Comment: Also how come React Native lets you do this, and it's ok then in Apple's policy? Again, I see apps do this all the time.

Comment: Again, JavaScript is an interpreted language. It's always delivered as source. Swift is a compiled language. As to why Apple allows React native apps to deliver updates outside of the app store, I have no idea. That sounds like a violation of Apple's policy to me.